# insert into <archiveTable> using top in while loop

Tags: sql-server

I need to archive let say Order table to OrderArchive table using SQL statement

Order table has 10,000 records.

I need to insert into OrderArchive table from Order  with top 1000 rows in while loop.

How can I achieve this in SQL Server

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Why are you using a while loop for this small number of records? 2. Do you need to delete from Order and insert to OrderArchive for your archive process?

Comment: no of records in just sample. yes i need to delete from Order and insert to OrderArchive

Comment: I really love this word `lakh`. A lakha records!

Comment: To save anyone else googling "A lakh or lac is a unit in the Indian numbering system equal to one hundred thousand"

Comment: @Martin Smith high five!

Comment: @Sujith - What version of SQL Server are you on? If SQL Server 2005+ you could use the OUTPUT clause on the delete on Order to Insert into OrderArchive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while 1=1
begin

insert into OrderArchive
select top 1000 * from Order o
where not exists (select top 1 1 from OrderArchive oa where oa.id = o.id)

if @@rowcount = 0 
break;

end
```

If you want to delete and insert deleted rows into Archive, there's a better solution:

```
delete o
output deleted.* into OrderArchive
from Order o
where o.ToDelete = 1
```